# MySQL table structure for JSTree

Tags: mysql, jstree

I'm looking for the most practical way to save the node data for my JSTree.

Currently I have everything stored in a single MySQL table with each row holding the data for each full branch. Each row is unique, meaning there are no 2 rows with all the columns exactly the same.   The problem with this is it leads to lots of data duplication.

I have tried setting up an adjacency list, but again with only allowing the reference of one parent ID it leads to lots of duplication.   This also increases the possibility of linking errors.

I also considered the nested set model, however with having 100,000+ branches, adding data gets rather expensive.

I'm also currently stuck using MySQL.

So the question becomes, what is my best option to store the tree data keeping retrieval time to a minimum, keeping duplicates to a minimum, and easy to update/add new data?

Comment: How about keeping whole tree as a JSON string in one record?

Comment: A JSON string for a 100,000+ branch tree would be unmanageable in my opinion.   Plus. unless i'm missing something, there is really no difference between that and the flat list i'm using now.